# multiple OR condition in data frame r language

Tags: r

Working with data frame, I need to create a new column based on OR condition on values of a categorical variable. I have following example to show you what I needm but my solution is not elegant as I am doing it one condition at a time

```
my.data <- as.data.frame(c("bob", "deb", "tom", "lucy"))

colnames(my.data) <- c("name.is")

my.data$gender.is <- "female"

my.data$gender.is[my.data$name.is == "bob"] <- "male"

my.data$gender.is[my.data$name.is == "tom"] <- "male"

my.data$gender.is
```

I wanted to do something like the following but it did not work

```
my.data$gender.is[my.data$name.is == c("bob","tom")] <- "male"
```

But this only assigns male to bob; the first match instance

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `%in%`operator

```
my.data$gender.is[my.data$name.is %in% c("bob","tom")] <- "male"
```